# How to use Syslog in Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, syslog, rsyslog

I’m developing a Python Django REST API. Currently, I need to incorporate a logger to Syslog.

Do I need to just define the logger and Syslog handler in the Settings.py?

I’m relatively new to Django and using the Syslog protocol, so I appreciate any help and what Python modules to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for example use the *syslog* library to log messages.

Using it, is pretty easy.

```
import syslog

# create syslog handle
syslog.openlog(ident="settings.py", facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)

# log some message
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "Some log message.")
```

The log message will not get written to `/var/log/local0.log` - probably it will also get written to `/var/log/rsyslog` or `/var/log/messages` depending on the standard configuration of your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file.